# DllImport Permission

Tags: c#, winforms, security, interop

I have a windows forms application that makes an external call to a dll. 
When this dll is loaded from a subdirectory of my application (using the PATH environment variable), it fails in the following method with a directory access problem (The external method needs to write a temporary file in the dll directory):

```
[DllImport("DarumaFrameWork.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int tCFEncerrar_NFCe_Daruma(string pszMsgPromocional);
```

When I load the dll from my application directory, it works correctly. I believe it is because of any access permission. Is there a way to define the external method will need access to it's own dll directory?

Comment: The dll will share it's permissions with the application which calls it. This is because permissions can only be given to a process. It is not possible to give different permissions to a dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting VS as admin. Anything you build and run within VS will share the permission of VS.